# In mysql if column datatype is integer, would it allow to store long value in int data type column?

Tags: mysql

Suppose i want to store long value in int data type column, it would allow me to store it?

Comment: No, there are some limits for int type, you can use bigint instead.

Answer (score 6):

As documented under [Integer Types (Exact Value) - `INTEGER`, `INT`, `SMALLINT`, `TINYINT`, `MEDIUMINT`, `BIGINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html):

> MySQL supports the SQL standard integer types `INTEGER` (or `INT`) and `SMALLINT`. As an extension to the standard, MySQL also supports the integer types `TINYINT`, `MEDIUMINT`, and `BIGINT`. The following table shows the required storage and range for each integer type.
>
> ```
> +-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
> |   Type    | Storage |    Minimum Value     |    Maximum Value     |
> |           | (Bytes) |  (Signed/Unsigned)   |  (Signed/Unsigned)   |
> +-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
> | TINYINT   | 1       | -128                 | 127                  |
> |           |         | 0                    | 255                  |
> +-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
> | SMALLINT  | 2       | -32768               | 32767                |
> |           |         | 0                    | 65535                |
> +-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
> | MEDIUMINT | 3       | -8388608             | 8388607              |
> |           |         | 0                    | 16777215             |
> +-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
> | INT       | 4       | -2147483648          | 2147483647           |
> |           |         | 0                    | 4294967295           |
> +-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
> | BIGINT    | 8       | -9223372036854775808 | 9223372036854775807  |
> |           |         | 0                    | 18446744073709551615 |
> +-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
> ```

The data type required for a "long" value will [depend on the language and architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Long_integer) for which you define "long".  In some common cases, it means a 4-byte integer (`INT` in MySQL) whilst in other common cases it means an 8-byte integer (`BIGINT` in MySQL); in less common cases, it could mean a different width entirely.